# Flutter: correctly constrain Column widget width to widest child?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a new flutter developer and am stuck with a problem.

I have a simple app that has a `Column` with 2 children. The first column has a `Container` with 2 icons. The second column has multiple child widgets in a grid layout.

I want the `Scaffold` width to be set to the second column width (which is controlled by its child widgets). So that the enclosing `Container` which draws a border around the app equal to the width of the bottom column child.

Here' my example code: https://dartpad.dev/0afd14981917d7464f6ff68719859c1e

One way I found is to wrap the column view in a `Row` with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, but then the first `Column`'s `Container` **does not** expand to the full width of the bottom child. I want the 2 icons in the first column to be equally spaced within the `Column`.

Is there a way to get to [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmtbx.png)?

Edit: I saw the question downvoted, but I don't know why? I have listed all the steps I performed and could not get a resolution. I am new to flutter so I am sure I haven't researched all possible documentation. But I have tried to use `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets to wrap the first `Column` and couldn't get it to work.

In fact, if I use `Expanded`, there is an exception thrown in the framework. I couldn't understand it which is why I am posting for help on this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I ran through lot of documentation, I stumbled on `IntrinsicWidth` class that sizes itself to its child widget. There seems to be some performance effects due to its use, but I am not sure how my app is affected.

From its [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html):

> This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.

I wrapped the `Column` widget with `IntrinsicWidth` and got my answer.

There might be a better answer out there, but currently I am too novice to find it.